# How many Veterans have been or are currently in Congress

Tags: data-request, government, data.gov

I am trying to track down how many veterans have been and are currently in Congress

The closest thing I have found is this [PDF](http://www.hqafsa.org/aoc/113.pdf) but it only gives me the 113 congresses I would like to find something a little bit easier to machine-read, and also a little more complete with past data so I can develop a proper graphical depiction.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vital Statistics on Congress](http://www.brookings.edu/research/reports/2013/07/vital-statistics-congress-mann-ornstein) from the Brookings Institute has some data about this available in Excel.

The "Vital Statistics Chapter 1- Demographics of Members of Congress" workbook has a worksheet, "1-8", which has the title "Prior Occupations of Representatives, 83rd - 113th Congresses, 1953 - 2014"  Veteran is one of the lines.

Comment: If only this Brookings Institute data was more machine readable!

Comment: any insight into what is the difference between Military and Veteran is in the chart?

Comment: No. Best to ask Brookings, I think.